# Damage over time unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I want to make spell damage over time. So here is my code:

```
public class Spell : MonoBehaviour
 {
    public float damage = 1.0f;
    public bool ignoreCaster = true;
    public float delayBeforeCasting = 0.4f;
    public float applyEveryNSeconds = 1.0f;
    public int applyDamageNTimes = 5;

    private bool delied = false;

    private int appliedTimes = 0;
    void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        IDamageable takeDamage = other.gameObject.GetComponent<IDamageable>();
        if(takeDamage != null)
        {
            StartCoroutine(CastDamage(takeDamage));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator CastDamage(IDamageable damageable)
    {
        if(!delied)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayBeforeCasting);
            delied = true;
        }

        while(appliedTimes < applyDamageNTimes)
        {
            damageable.TakeDamage(damage);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(applyEveryNSeconds);
            appliedTimes++;
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is where `while` starts. I want to check if `appliedTimes < applyDamageNTimes`, then if it is true to do damage, wait for delay (applyEveryNSeconds) and then check again but i am not handy with coroutine and for some reason it is not doing that.

Here is working code. Also look for other answers if someone need!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spell : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float damage = 1.0f;
    public bool ignoreCaster = true;
    public float delayBeforeCasting = 0.0f;
    public float applyEveryNSeconds = 1.0f;
    public int applyDamageNTimes = 1;

    private bool delied = false;

    private int appliedTimes = 0;

    private bool test = false;
    void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        IDamageable takeDamage = other.gameObject.GetComponent<IDamageable>();
        if(takeDamage != null)
        {
            StartCoroutine(CastDamage(takeDamage));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator CastDamage(IDamageable damageable)
    {
        if(!test && appliedTimes <= applyDamageNTimes || !test && applyEveryNSeconds == 0)
        {
            test = true;
            if(!delied)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayBeforeCasting);
                delied = true;
            }
            else
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(applyEveryNSeconds);
            }
            damageable.TakeDamage(damage);
            appliedTimes++;
            test = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe a dumb question : Why does the `appliedTimes++` is not inside the while loop ?

Comment: @Hellium I think that is the answer. it should be inside loop

Comment: @Hellium I was trying something and when i was putting code back to original i forgot to put that back in so i edited to post.

Comment: So basically instead of 5 dmg it deals 118 and i do not know why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OnTriggerStay is called every frame 2 objects are colliding. This means that an asynchronous instance of CastDamage coroutine is called every frame. So what happens is that you're getting a whole lot of damage per seconds, which simulates not any damage per second, hehe.

So change OnTriggerStay to OnTriggerEnter.

Depending on the kind of spell it is, I'd rather create a DPS script and apply that to the game object so...

- Spell hits Object
- AddComponent< MyDamageSpell>();

And then the MyDpsSpell does damage every N seconds to the Object it's on, and removes itself when it is done:

// Spell.cs

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) {
    // if you don't want more than 1 dps instance on an object, otherwise remove if
    if (col.GetComponent<MyDpsAbility>() == null) {
        var dps = col.AddComponent<MyDpsAbility>();
        dps.Damage = 10f;
        dps.ApplyEveryNSeconds(1);
        // and set the rest of the public variables
    }
}
```

// MyDpsAbility.cs

```
public float Damage { get; set; }
public float Seconds { get; set; }
public float Delay { get; set; }
public float ApplyDamageNTimes { get; set; }
public float ApplyEveryNSeconds { get; set; }

private int appliedTimes = 0;

void Start() {
    StartCoroutine(Dps());
}

IEnumerator Dps() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Delay);

    while(appliedTimes < ApplyDamageNTimes)
    {
        damageable.TakeDamage(damage);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(ApplyEveryNSeconds);
        appliedTimes++;
    }

    Destroy(this);
}
```

If it's an aura spell where units take damage every second they're in range you could do something like:

```
float radius = 10f;
float damage = 10f;
void Start() {
    InvokeRepeating("Dps", 1);
}


void Dps() {
    // QueryTriggerInteraction.Collide might be needed
    Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(gameObject.position, radius);

    foreach(Collider col in hitColliders) {
        col.getComponent<IDamagable>().TakeDamage(10);
    }
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html

Comment: That looks interesting. I will try that but since you are here could you explain me this. I made it does every `N` seconds but `if` statement inside IEnumerator is confusing me. I edited my question so read the end and if you know what is happening please answer me

Comment: I updated my answer with a lot more code as well, for different scenarios. I will look at your update!

Comment: That's nice. The main issue is still "OnTriggerStay". The method is called every frame (60 times per seconds) which means every second 60 CastDamage is started and running at the same time.

Comment: Yea but it does nothing since when it enters Cast Damage it check `if !test` and stop (since that bool is false every N sec)

Comment: Well there's no reason to have a bad solution when a good solution is easier and better in all aspects: less, code easier to read and more performant and less risk of bugs. The issue may be solved but it's not a very good solution. You're still creating a coroutine, finding components etc every frame when you don't need to. It will also just work with 1 object, but maybe that's what you want. In my answer you find solutions to every scenario you might have, but if you just want something to work your solution will tecehnically work. :)

Comment: At first i didn't understand your code becuase of this `var dps = col.AddComponent<MyDpsAbility>();`. Does it add Script to object (enemy)

Comment: Yes, it adds the script to the enemy. And then that ability does damage to the enemy it is on and then removes itself. This way every DPS-ability "thinks" for itself so you can add it to many different enemies and it will work individually

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146421/discussion-between-aleksa-ristic-and-maakep).

Answer (score 1):

Why not create, instead a system that applies auras to in-game characters? For example, if a spell like this adds a damage over time debuff it could instead add the debuff-aura script to the game object and then remove itself once its conditions are met.

Comment: I do not quiet get it. You think to insert code into gameobject itself (one that need to take dmg), and then when conditions is met (collide with spell) i apply it?